# Was there a version of The Diamond Age that ended abruptly, like a cliffhanger that called for a sequel?

Tags: novel, diamond-age

I'm an old guy and maybe my memory isn't so good but I could swear I read a version of *The Diamond Age* more than thirty years ago. It ended abruptly, completely like a cliffhanger that called for a sequel. I remember Mr. Stephenson promising a sequel. The sequel never came. I just reread the book. Maybe halfway through, about the time Hackworth encounters the drummers, it doesn't seem familiar. Also I don't remember a Miranda or a Carl Hollywood from my first encounter.

So my basic question is. Am I crazy? Or did this book appear in a shorter version and then some years later in the fleshed out version that is now for sale.

TLDR: I want to know if there was a version of Neal Stephenson's novel *The Diamond Age* that was published prior to 1995 and was considerably shorter than the present 1995 version for sale on Amazon

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know if there was a version of Neal Stephenson's novel 'The Diamond Age' that was published prior to 1995 and was considerably shorter than the present 1995 version for sale on Amazon

Comment: I wonder if *The Diamond Age* or a story that became *The Diamond Age* was initially serialized, or published as a short story or novella?

Comment: That's certainly a typical Stephenson ending to encounter, but every edition of TDA I've read has the usual one.

Comment: I thought of that but I can picture the cover of the novel. White. I can also clearly remember how pissed I was at the ending and the fact that the sequel never appeared. But I guess the sequel did appear although it is weird that it was conjoined with the original for one price instead of being a separate book. Perhaps the whole thing was rewritten, new characters and plot lines added to make a 600 page novel reasonable. Or maybe I am totally crazy and imagined the whole thing.

Comment: There's a short story called "from the Diamond Age" published in [Hive of Dreams: Contemporary Science Fiction from the Pacific Northwest](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2692257) which _could_ be an excerpt from Diamond Age. According to the ISFDB, it was never serialized.

Comment: What parts do you remember were missing from the short version?

Comment: It was a long time ago but I think in the shorter version there was no Miranda and no carl Hollywood. There also was no Mainland Chinese invasion of the coastal republic. Perhaps also no mouse army and maybe even no creation of the quarter million books for the infants on the boats and maybe none of that business at all. I remember it being almost entirely about the New Victorians with a second storyline about Nell and Princess nell. But I could be wrong. Though that book seriously impressed me. The main thing was the cliffhanger ending when Hackworth awoke in the drummers world.

Answer (score 2):

I have the hard cover first edition (1995).  There is no indication on the copyright page that any part of the text had been published previously.